# Insert a text before slash "/" character in bash scripts

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a line in a file as below:

```
2 14 * * * /run/opt/server/autoi.sh
```

And I want to insert "root" before /run/opt/server/autoi.sh as below:

```
2 14 * * * root /run/opt/server/autoi.sh
```

I have tried the following command

```
sed '//run/i root' filename
```

but it gives the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

Could you please help me to find a fix for it?

Comment: any character other than ``\`` and newline character can be used as delimiter... and `i` command will add a line before the matching line, not sure why you used that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different separator character, and you need to use the `s` command to substitute, e.g:

```
sed 's@/run@root /run@' filename
```

or without repeating `/run`:

```
sed 's@/run@root &@' filename
```

Comment: @Sundeep you're right, added your suggestion. I usually repeat the match if it is short enough (that is, if it takes me less time to type than to remember what the special characters are...)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong `sed` command.  The `i` command will insert a new line before the matching line, and of course, `//run` is not a valid regex at all.

The general form of a `sed` command is

```
<address> <action>
```

where *address* could be a regex or a line number, and *action* is a command.

In fact, you want an action without an address, which means it will be applied to every input line; and the action you want to perform is a substitution.

```
sed 's%/run%root &%' filename
```

We are using the `&` convenience shorthand to repeat the string which matched the first regex, and an alternate regex separator instead of `/` so that `/` does not itself get interpreted as a regex separator (equivalently, you could backslash-escape it, but here, that produces something called [*leaning toothpick syndrome).*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)

This will print the results to standard output, not modify the file.  Once you have verified that you get the results you want, you might want to add an `-i` option to modify the input file. (On some platforms, such as *BSD -- which includes MacOS -- you need `-i ''` with an empty argument.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply substitute very first `/` with `root /` as follows.

```
sed 's/\//root \//'  Input_file
```

Comment: @down voter: Please give an explanation for -ve vote here, as it discourages me that without letting know someone is providing -ve to my answer :(

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -e 's/run/root\/run/' abc
```

Example:

```
[root@myIP tmp]# cat abc 
2 14 * * * /run/opt/server/autoi.sh
[root@myIP tmp]# sed -e 's/run/root\/run/' abc
2 14 * * * /root/run/opt/server/autoi.sh
```

Edited: To add a username. this should do the trick

```
[root@myIP tmp]# sed -e 's/\//root \//' abc
2 14 * * * root /run/opt/server/autoi.sh
```

Comment: The intent is to add a user name before the command, not add something to the path.  The crontab format for the  `root` user is different, and requires a user name field after the five time specification fields, before the command to run.